# Visualize tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier weights

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've played with tensorflow's LinearClassifier data with the famous titanic dataset.

(my question itself is down at the bottom - this is all some code for the model itself)

So I have my feature columns:

```
CONTINUOUS_COLS = ['Age', 'Fare']
CATEGORICAL_COLS = ['Sex', 'Pclass', 'Title']
LABELS_COL = 'Survived'

sex_col = sparse_column_with_keys('Sex', keys=['male', 'female'])
title_col = sparse_column_with_hash_bucket('Title', 10)
fare_class_col = sparse_column_with_keys('Pclass', keys=['1','2','3'])
age_col = real_valued_column('Age')
fare_col = real_valued_column('Fare')
```

my input function:

```
def create_input_fn(df):
    continous_features = {k: tf.constant(df[k].values) for k in CONTINUOUS_COLS}
    categorical_features = {k : tf.SparseTensor(
        indices=[[0,i] for i in range(df[k].size)],
        values=df[k].values,
        dense_shape=[df[k].size, 1]
    ) for k in CATEGORICAL_COLS}
    feature_cols = {**continous_features, **categorical_features}
    labels = tf.constant(df[LABELS_COL].values)
    return feature_cols, labels
```

and my model:

```
clf = LinearClassifier(feature_columns=[sex_col, fare_class_col, age_col, fare_col, title_col],
    optimizer=tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(
        learning_rate=0.5,
        l1_regularization_strength=1.0,
        l2_regularization_strength=1.0),
    model_dir=tempfile.TemporaryDirectory().name)
```

Now when i run the model, it does okaish, and I want to look at the weights of the model to better visualize them.

So `clf.weights_` exists (although it is listed as deprecated), so I just pull them out manually:

```
for var in clf.get_variable_names():
    if var.endswith('weights'):
        print(f'{var} -> {clf.get_variable_value(var)}')
```

And I get some decent results:

```
linear/Pclass/weights -> [[ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [-0.01772301]]
linear/Sex/weights -> [[-0.07285357]
 [ 0.        ]]
linear/Title/weights -> [[ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [-0.03760524]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]]
```

Now my question is - How do I pull out the **keys** that were originally used?
So I could better match the numbers, for example with Sex - the keys are originally mapped to male/female.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For `sparse_column_with_keys`:
`sex_col.lookup_config.keys  # ('male', 'female')`

So something like:

```
matched = {}
weights = clf.get_variable_value('linear/Sex/weights')  # np array
for index, key in enumerate(sex_col.lookup_config.keys):
    matched[key] = weights[index]
```

and there are some other interesting attributes when you `dir(sex_col.lookup_config)` and check the method docstrings at: [Source for SparseColumn Feature classes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column.py)
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column.py

I didn't figure out a map from `sparse_column_with_hash_bucket` yet

If you had the `tf.contrib.layers.bucketized_column` like age_buckets in the tutorial:
`age_buckets.boundaries`